# charts not appearing for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, chart.js, asp.net-ajax

I'm still a beginner in ASP.NET MVC, I created charts for one of my models and it worked; when I tried that same method for another model I have in the same project, it didn't work.

the controller (DowntimeController)

```
using ASPNETPFE.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using ASPNETPFE.Models.Domain;

namespace ASPNETPFE.Controllers
{
    //for register
    [Authorize]
    //
    public class DowntimeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MVCDemoDbContext _context;  //_context and context were both simply dbContext 

        public DowntimeController(MVCDemoDbContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }

        
public IActionResult IndexDowntime()
        {
            var result = dbContext.Trss
                .GroupBy(x => x.Reason)
                .Select(s => new DowntimeOccurence
                {
                    DowntimeSum = s.Sum(d => d.Downtime),

                    Reason = s.Key,
                    Occurence = s.Count()
                })
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.DowntimeSum)
                .ToList();
            //
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                var downtimeSummary = new DowntimeOccurence
                {
                    DowntimeSum = item.DowntimeSum,
                    Occurence = item.Occurence,
                    Reason = item.Reason
                };

                dbContext.Downtime.Add(downtimeSummary);
            }

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return View(result);
        }
                   


        //////for the chart
        public IActionResult ShowDdata()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public List<object> GetDdata()
        {
            List<object> data = new List<object>();

            List<string> labels = _context.Downtime.Select(p => p.Reason).ToList();
            data.Add(labels);

            List<int> values = _context.Downtime.Select(p => p.Occurence).ToList();
            data.Add(values);

            return data;
        }

    }
}
```

the model: (DowntimeOccurence)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class DowntimeOccurence
{
    //
    [Key]    
    public int Idd { get; set; }  ///for the charts of downtime
    //

    public int DowntimeSum { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public int Occurence { get; set; }
}
```

the view (Showddata)

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!--<input id="ID" value="Show Graph" type="button" />-->
<!--where we select the type of graph we want-->
<p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <label><b>Chart-Type</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <select id="ChartType" class="form-control" style="width:150px;">
                <option selected>--Select Chart Type--</option>
                <option>bar</option>
                <option>line</option>
                <!--<option>doughnut</option>-->
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <input id="ID" value="Show Graph" type="button" />
        </div>
    </div>
</p>


<br />

<div id="ChartView">
    <!--we created a canvas and it gets refreshed automatically with every click inside the div-->
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>          <!--the chart.js reference-->

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#ID").click(function () {

            var chartType = $("#ChartType").val();
            var chartView = document.getElementById('ChartView');

            chartView.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
            $('#ChartView').append('<canvas id="myChart" style="max-width:750px;max-height:400px;"><canvas>');


            $.ajax({                                       //ajax method to fetch the data from the db
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Trss/GetData",
                data: "",
                contextType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccessResult,
                error: OnError
            });

            function OnSuccessResult(data) {

                var _data = data;
                var _chartLabels = _data[0].map(d => new Date(d).toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }));;
                var _chartData = _data[1];


                var barColor = ["blue", "purple", "orange", "brown", "green", "red"];

                new Chart("myChart",                   //this is where we generate the graph
                    {
                        type: chartType,
                        data: {
                            labels: _chartLabels,                           
                            datasets: [{
                                backgroundColor: barColor,
                                data: _chartData
                            }]
                        }
                    });

            }

            function OnError(err) {

            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

can somebody help me please?

I tried to look for solutions but to no avail.

Comment: Does the `GetData` return the response successfully? If yes, can you show the response as the snippet in the question? Thanks.

Comment: public IActionResult IndexDowntime() Not Used?

Comment: @RomanIeromenko IndexDowntime will display the totaldowntime, occurence and reason in another view as a table; and i wanted to create the charts corresponding to them in another view

Comment: @YongShun I think it is not, I just realized that IndexDowntime is not saving the data to my db, it gets displayed without being saved , so that is probably the issue, thank u for bringing it up, now it's a different problem (xD)

Comment: IndexDowntime just getting result IQueryable j,jects and nothing more

Comment: i modified it, still nothing

Comment: @RomanIeromenko idk what u mean, but it is supposedly getting data from the database, modifying it (sum), than saving the new changes in another table in the same db and displaying the result, but, .. that's not the reality of things;

Comment: So real concern is this method IndexDowntime